# Workspace.Coin.SpinningCoin:7: attempt to index nil with 'leaderstats'

Tags: roblox

The following code works 95% of the time, then occasionally, it fails and I have no idea why. The strange thing is the rest of the script still runs, the print lines work and cash is added. Is Roblox Studio just buggy or have I done something wrong? - BTW, I have ten rebirths which is why I get 35 cash instead of ten.

```
`script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)

    local plr = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    local GiveCash = 10
    local RebirthMultiplier = 0.25
    cash = plr.leaderstats.Cash.Value 
    print(cash)
    rebirths = plr.leaderstats.Rebirths.Value
    print(rebirths)
    
    script.Disabled = true
    script.Parent.Transparency = 1
    script.Parent.CanCollide = false    
    plr.leaderstats.Cash.Value = cash + GiveCash + (rebirths * GiveCash * RebirthMultiplier)
    wait(3)
    script.Parent.Transparency=0
    script.Parent.CanCollide = false
    script.Disabled = false

end)`
```

[Roblox Studio Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc86Y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Touched` signal fires whenever anything touches it, including objects that aren't player character models. You need to account for the possibility that `Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter` does not return a player.

```
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local plr = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    if not plr then
        return
    end
```